# What all folder i can add in the 'res' folder?

Tags: android

Some that I know are color, layout, drawable,values.
 layout and drawable for different resolution and density.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) documentation.